What is the effect of filing a CCPA deletion request to the the credit reporting agencies?
Credit reporting agencies are required to comply with consumer privacy laws. Some of them, like TransUnion, do so transparently. They report they had 275 deletion requests, of which all 275 they obliged.
What happens to these 275 people which TransUnion now has no data of whatsoever.
I assume bankruptcy persists as they must link into the civil proceedings which are public 3rd party (government) information? Is it ever advantageous to request full deletion and rebuild from scratch?

Nothing happens. Credit reporting agencies are exempt from CCPA. There may be additional personal data that TransUnion is required to delete regarding its own services and products, but CCPA deletion requests have no bearing on credit reporting.
See the California FAQ:

Credit reporting agencies like Equifax, Experian, and TransUnion can still collect and disclose your credit information, subject to regulation under the Fair Credit Reporting Act. Learn more about your rights under the Fair Credit Reporting Act here. Learn more about how to check and fix your credit report here.

See also here:

(d) (1) This title shall not apply to an activity involving the collection, maintenance, disclosure, sale, communication, or use of any personal information bearing on a consumer’s creditworthiness, credit standing, credit capacity, character, general reputation, personal characteristics, or mode of living by a consumer reporting agency, as defined in subdivision (f) of Section 1681a of Title 15 of the United States Code, by a furnisher of information, as set forth in Section 1681s-2 of Title 15 of the United States Code, who provides information for use in a consumer report, as defined in subdivision (d) of Section 1681a of Title 15 of the United States Code, and by a user of a consumer report as set forth in Section 1681b of Title 15 of the United States Code.

